# Increase max upload file size in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, filesize

How can I increase the maximum file size that can be uploaded in Shiny beyond 30 MB?

Answer (score 3):

Set the variable in global options

```
 options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2)
```